# Update badly formed XML to allow parsing

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xml

I have inherited a production system that needs some fine tuning to enable easy extract of the result set.  A record gets added to a table which contains an XML field, with contents similar to the below:

```
<PROG>PROGX_</PROG><STNTYPE>LEAKTEST</STNTYPE><STNID>S1</STNID><TRCODE>SN_REQUEST</TRCODE><OPERATORID>222</OPERATORID><PARTID>PARTID</PARTID><TRSTATUS>0000</TRSTATUS><TRTEXT>TEST OK</TRTEXT><T1_USL>0.45</T1_USL><T1_LSL>-0.45</T1_LSL><T1_RESULT>05,CC/M</T1_RESULT><T1_STATUS>OK</T1_STATUS><OVERALL_RESULT>1</OVERALL_RESULT><OVERALL_STATUS>OK</OVERALL_STATUS>
```

However, I believe the formatting of the XML is invalid and I want to be able to clean this up a bit, by adding a root and grouping this a bit better.  Something similar to along the lines of:

```
<RESULTSET>
    <PROG>PROGX_</PROG>
    <STNTYPE>LEAKTEST</STNTYPE>
    <STNID>S1</STNID>
    ...etc...
    <OVERALL_STATUS>OK</OVERALL_STATUS>
</RESULTSET>
```

(The idea being then that I can use SQL views to then properly split this).

Any ideas if this is possible?  I'm new to XML on SQL.

Comment: What do you mean by "clean this up a bit"?

Comment: Improve the structure, add the grouping node etc.  I then want to be able to correctly parse this using a view into the child components as I then need to do some analysis on some of the results being captured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this information on SQL Server without adding a root element:

```
create table tbl (foo xml);

insert into tbl values ('<PROG>PROGX_</PROG><STNTYPE>LEAKTEST</STNTYPE><STNID>S1</STNID><TRCODE>SN_REQUEST</TRCODE><OPERATORID>222</OPERATORID><PARTID>PARTID</PARTID><TRSTATUS>0000</TRSTATUS><TRTEXT>TEST OK</TRTEXT><T1_USL>0.45</T1_USL><T1_LSL>-0.45</T1_LSL><T1_RESULT>05,CC/M</T1_RESULT><T1_STATUS>OK</T1_STATUS><OVERALL_RESULT>1</OVERALL_RESULT><OVERALL_STATUS>OK</OVERALL_STATUS>
');
```

```
select 
    foo.value('(/PROG)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') PROG,
    foo.value('(/STNTYPE)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') STNTYPE,
    foo.value('(/STNID)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') STNID
from   tbl;
GO
```

> ```
> PROG   | STNTYPE  | STNID
> :----- | :------- | :----
> PROGX_ | LEAKTEST | S1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=df3474d5e931eec76c046b40c261c87e)*

Comment: Thanks for this approach. I figured there was an alternative method to get what I needed, and this does it.  Much appreciated.

Comment: I'm glad to help.